# How to configure signalR's connection string in the Function using the managed identity?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-managed-identity

I have a Function App running on `.net6` using the isolated worker. I have built the `negociate` Function which allows to return to an authenticated client the SignalR endpoint.

```
[Function("negotiate")]
public Task<HttpResponseData> NegotiateAsync
(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, Verbs.Post)]
    HttpRequestData httpRequestData,
    [SignalRConnectionInfoInput(HubName = "updates", UserId = "{headers.x-ms-client-principal-id}")] 
    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo
)
{
    [...]

    HttpResponseData httpResponseData = httpRequestData.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    httpResponseData.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    string originalConnectionInfo = JsonSerializer.Serialize(connectionInfo);
    await httpResponseData.WriteStringAsync(originalConnectionInfo);

    return httpResponseData;
}
```

I have activated the System-Assigned identity on the SignalR instance:

[image: SignalR's system identity]

I have set the role of SignalR App Server to the Function App (and its `staging` slot):

[image: SignalR's App Server]

Now, I have to specify the endpoint of SignalR to the Function App. Usually, it is set up in the configuration using either the default `AzureSignalRConnectionString` or a custom one. Following the procedure when accessing storage accounts using Managed Identity, I simply the URL in the `AzureSignalRConnectionString` setting such as `https://<signalr-name>.service.signalr.net`.

However I end up with the following error:

Exception while executing function: Functions.negotiate <--- Connection string missing required properties endpoint and accesskey. (Parameter 'connectionString')

**Question**

How do I configure signalR's connection string in the Function using the managed identity?

Answer (score 0):

I just read the (unfortunate) solution in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-authorize-managed-identity#azure-functions-signalr-bindings):

[image: Oh no]

So the answer is no, I can't use managed identity with a SignalR bindin **in an Function running in the isolated worker**. For now.

**Update**: added precision regarding the worker.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the support for Azure Identity in SignalR extension for isolated workers has not been released yet. For in-process model, SignalR trigger binding supports Azure Identity since 1.7.0-beta.1.